# Why temporary assigned value is not changed in the next iteration

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing some weird issue with the following code:

```
for($i=0;$i<count($job1);$i++){
    for($j=0;$j<count($jobidcomm);$j++){
        if(!$jobidcomm->isEmpty() && $job1[$i]->job_pos_id==$jobidcomm[$j]->job_id){
            $job[$i]=$job1[$i]; 
            break;
        } 
        else if (!$recruiter==null)
        {
            if(!$job1[$i]->commission_percentage==null){
                $newamt=(($job1[$i]->min_sal*$job1[$i]->commission_percentage)/100)*($recruiter/100);
            }
            else{
                $newamt=($job1[$i]->commission_flat_amt)*($recruiter/100);
            }
            $job1[$i]->commissionHalfAmt=$newamt; //here is i m having problem(this is temprory assign data)
            $job[$i]=$job1[$i]; 
        }
    }
}
```

suppose at `j=0` it executes `$recruiter` condition where I assign a temp value but when `j` becomes 1 *(i.e `j=1`)*, then it goes inside this

```
if(!$jobidcomm->isEmpty() && $job1[$i]->job_pos_id==$jobidcomm[$j]->job_id)
```

above condition, in this condition I want to reset `job1` as it originally was(like before without temp assigned data)

Comment: If this is just a temporary value, why are you doing it in the first place? It's never used.

Comment: @Barmar but how i can reset it to previous value mean in second if condition i m modify value but in first if condition value not get modify by deafult value please help me how i can reset array to before modify array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the old value in a variable before the inner loop.

```
for($i=0;$i<count($job1);$i++){
    $saveCommission = $job1[$i]->commissionHalfAmt;
    for($j=0;$j<count($jobidcomm);$j++){
        if(!$jobidcomm->isEmpty() && $job1[$i]->job_pos_id==$jobidcomm[$j]->job_id){
            $job[$i]=$job1[$i]; 
            break;
        } 
        else if (!$recruiter==null)
        {
            if(!$job1[$i]->commission_percentage==null){
                $newamt=(($job1[$i]->min_sal*$job1[$i]->commission_percentage)/100)*($recruiter/100);
            }
            else{
                $newamt=($job1[$i]->commission_flat_amt)*($recruiter/100);
            }
            $job1[$i]->commissionHalfAmt=$newamt; //here is i m having problem(this is temprory assign data)
            $job[$i]=$job1[$i]; 
        }
    }
    $job1[$i]->commissionHalfAmt = $saveCommission;
}
```

BTW, you should learn to use `foreach()` when looping over array elements.

Comment: one last thing i want to know is foreach loop is better than for loop

Comment: It's just easier to write and read. You don't have to keep repeating `$arrayname[$i]`, you can just use `$element`. The fact that you're looping over an array is more obvious. It's especially helpful with nested loops over multi-dimensional arrays.